# How can I export 1,000,000 records to an Excel file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export, xlsx

I have a table that contains more than a million records. I need to write this data on an excel file.

The problem is that the process is taking too much of time and it never completes. May be the process is using too much of memory or the excel sheet limit has been reached.

The process works fine for lower data limits(Eg: 10000). I am using WriteXLSX gem for data writing.

Is there a way to write large volumes of records on an excel file?

Comment: Which server are you using for rails and what is the error after time-out ?

Comment: Webserver - nginx, Application server - Passenger 5. The problem is that the process is taking too much of time. That is, it might take more than 30 minutes. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest do not create too big files. Next time, you still have to split one file into several smaller ones to read it without out of memory.

Comment: If it is a one time process then you can overwrite timeout for nginx and passenger then run your code and export your data or the other way is run background task and update limit every time until last record is not exported.

Comment: Using a worker for this this will be the best way I guess. You can use gems like delayed_job to achieve this.

Comment: You may wish to question whether Excel is the best tool for manipulating that many records.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this write to Excel file in the same process that server is running, then I strongly advise you do this in background job (sidekiq or delayed jobs, there are a lot of bg engines out there).

If it is a separate process, then check your background engine settings and bump memory limit, or time-out limit - it all depends on what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, but in reverse. I needed to create 600,000 objects based on a csv file that I uploaded to s3.

The best way to do this is to send it to a background job using Sidekiq to avoid timeouts.